# AppSync Multiple DynamoDB Storages Many to Many Relationship

Tags: graphql, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I have a question regarding AWS AppSync and the usage around it when it comes to having two data stores. In this case Tag & Pages are separate Data Stores with DynamoDB.

The problem I am facing is its usage around Many to Many relationships purely in AppSync. I am aware this can be done in Amplify but I am hoping for a solution purely in AppSync, VTL Resolvers via CDK.

Hoping I could pick the brains of more experienced folks within the AWS community as the resources I able to find is limited (when Amplify is wanting to be avoided)

Here is the schema

```
type Query {
  getPages: [Page]
  getPage(slug: String!): Page
  getTags: [Tag]
}

type Tag {
  updated_at: String
  created_at: String!
  name: String!
  description: String!
  short_name: String!
  classname: String!
  identifier: String!
}

type Page {
  slug: String!
  updated_at: String
  created_at: String!
  thumbnail: String
  content: String!
  title: String!
  description: String
  keywords: [String]
  tags: [Tag]
}

input PageInput {
  updated_at: String
  created_at: String!
  thumbnail: String
  content: String!
  title: String!
  description: String
  keywords: [String]
  tags: [String]
}

input TagInput {
  updated_at: String
  created_at: String!
  name: String!
  description: String!
  short_name: String!
  classname: String!
}

type Mutation {
  addPage(slug: String!, input: PageInput!): Page
  addTag(identifier: String!, input: TagInput!): Tag
  deletePage(slug: String!): Page
  deleteTag(identifier: String!): Tag
}
```

// Mapping Templates

```
# Page.tags.request.vtl
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "operation: "GetItem",
    "key": {
        "identifier": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($context.source.tags)
    }
}

# Page.tags.response.vtl
$util.toJson($ctx.result.items)
```

I want to be able to call either of getPages or getPage and have GraphQL be able to resolve the tags in both.

I have already set up a resolver for when Page.Tags is called as I was hoping I could store the tags identifiers and retrieve them from the table but it is not working as expected currently.

From reading up online do I need to create a connection type? something along the lines of "PageTagConnection" which essentially takes the identifiers for the aforementioned types (identifier for Tag & slug for Page) and build up a relation that way?

Then inside the resolver for PageTagConnection I will need to resolve identifiers for both in VTL and retrieve only all Tags that have the Tag identifier stored for that Page?

At the moment it is unclear as I cannot see the identifiers for Tag being stored.

Would appreciate any resources or wisdom shared very much Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem

Essentially on the Page.Tag Resolver I used BatchGetItem and iterated through the Page.Tags which are the identifiers for the Tags schema and are stored with the Page Items

Request Template iterates through the Identifiers and queries DynamoDB for all Tags that match the identifier.

Then in the resolver I return the items from the query

```
#if ($ctx.source.tags.size() <= 0) 
#return([])
#end

#set($ids = [])
#foreach($id in ${ctx.source.tags})
    #set($map = {})
    $util.qr($map.put("identifier", $util.dynamodb.toString($id)))
    $util.qr($ids.add($map))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
    "tables" : {
        "YourTableName": {
            "keys": $util.toJson($ids),
            "consistentRead": true
        }
    }
}

// Response

$util.toJson($ctx.result.data.YourTableName)
```

Note the mention of the table name "YourTableName" change this to your table.